# Any way to "close" a group of reminders all at once on OSX?

Tags: macos, ui, reminders

Every time I turn on my mac, a set of like 10 recurring reminder popups clog up my OSX Desktop screen.

I may be a procrastinator and all, but Reminders.app's interface on OSX feels downright buggy without a button to close all reminders at once, or at least all recurring reminders.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or something to make them all "close" at once? A "Saturday shortcut", lets call it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two fairly easy ways to do this:

### Option 1 (default):

With the default configuration of your mac, you can simply <kbd>option</kbd> + click the notification center icon in the top right corner of your screen. This will enable Do Not Disturb, which automatically dismisses all notifications and silences incoming notifications. If you wish to continue receiving notifications, you can <kbd>option</kbd> + click the notification center icon again. Your notifications that were on the screen will not re-appear.

### Option 2 (creating a keyboard shortcut):

1. Open **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control**
2. Enable the checkbox next to **Turn Do Not Disturb On/Off**
3. Click `none` to the right of the option
4. Set a shortcut.

[image: syspreferences screenshot]
<sup>Credit: [igeeksblog.com](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-enable-do-not-disturb-on-mac/)</sup>

Whenever you want to dismiss all notifications, press this shortcut twice.

Comment: I don't suppose you know if it's possible to close all reminders on an iPhone?

Comment: I was thinking about asking that question also but didn't think it was even possible. I think a shake gesture would be a good way to snooze all your reminders

Comment: @Little.Eden swipe down from the top to bring down the notifications, there are big (X) buttons - those will mass-delete notifications, but you may need to hit it once for each day.

Answer (score 0):

### Using an Alfred workflow

If you use Alfred, you have this workflow available: [Notification dismisser](https://github.com/zakyum/alfred-notification-dismisser). It will close all the currently displayed notifications with a shortcut or Alfred keyword. Super simple to use and works as expected.

### Without using Alfred

If you don't use Alfred, you have this option. Take the [main script](https://github.com/zakyum/alfred-notification-dismisser/blob/master/src/dismiss-active-notifications.applescript) from the workflow and using Automator save it as a "Quick Action". Then set a keyboard shortcut for it in System Preferences. Does the same as the workflow, albeit requires a bit more effort than clicking "install" as with Alfred.

<sub>*Full disclosure, I'm the author of the workflow and script. Hope it helps someone to save a couple precious seconds!*</sub>